# Apply function on two breeze matrices

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I would like to apply a function on two matrices like there is a `+` for the addition of two matrices. Something like `matrix1.map2(matrix2) { (valM1, valM2) => valM1 + valM2 }` giving a result matrix.

Comment: and what is the problem?, do you want to extend the Matrix type with a new function?

Comment: I thought there would have been something general available already. I might have to extend.

Comment: In what kind of function are you thinking about?

Comment: doesn't matter. I guess Breeze follows the algebraic rules rather being multi purpose. I thought of something like:  ((a,b) => if a > 0 then a else b}